# mySQL SELECT AS for multiple criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I need to combine these two queries into 1:

```
SELECT user1ID AS friendID FROM friends WHERE user2ID = '$userid'
UNION
SELECT user2ID AS friendID FROM friends WHERE user1ID = '$userid'
```

Then

```
SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE ID = friendID (that we just established)
```

Comment: `WHERE user2ID = ? OR user1ID = ?`

Comment: @Petah: The OP wants to `SELECT` different fields (user1ID and user2ID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess MySQL's `UNION` ([Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html)) keyword is what you are looking for.

EDIT due to edited question:

You will need a subquery for what you are trying to do (a `JOIN` might also work, but would be more complicated):

```
SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT user1ID AS friendID FROM friends WHERE user2ID = '$userid'
    UNION
    SELECT user2ID AS friendID FROM friends WHERE user1ID = '$userid'
)
```

Note that subqueries can cause performance issues in very large tables and/or complicated queries. You may want to refactor the subquery to a `JOIN` in that case.

Comment: This fixed it, but now I need one more step

Comment: `SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users JOIN friends ON (user1ID = :userID AND user2ID = users.id) OR (user2ID = :userID  AND user1ID = users.id)`

Comment: Just as @Petah wrote.

Comment: `SELECT users.firstName, users.lastName, friends.ID [...]`.